# symbols between equal tokens in string

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have made program which finds equal words in sentence.
I need to write program which calculates how much symbols is between equal tokens.

I know if the equal strings would be words[2] and words[5] then lenght between them would be
strlen(words[3])+strlen(words[4])

My code :

```
for (k=0; k<i-1; k++)
{
 for (j=k+1; j<i; j++)
  { 
             if (strcmp(words[k],words[j])==0) 
             {
             printf("equal words are [%s],%d,%d",words[k],k,j);



             break;
             }
```

But if my words are like

```
     words[k] and words[j]
```

How then i can know the lenght between them?

Comment: You have given the answer already :) 
_"I know if the equal strings would be words[2] and words[5] then lenght between them would be strlen(words[3])+strlen(words[4])"_ -- just formulate that approach as a for-loop, and then you will also see how 'k' and 'j' fit into the picture... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naïve answer would be to add another for loop once you've got a match:

```
for (k=0; k<i-1; k++)
{
    for (j=k+1; j<i; j++)
    { 
         if (strcmp(words[k],words[j])==0) 
         {
             int distance = 0;
             for (n=k+1; n < j; n++)
             {
                  distance += strlen(words[n]);
             }

             printf("equal words are [%s],%d,%d,(distance = %d)",words[k],k,j,distance);
             break;
         }
    }  
}
```

However, you can also keep track of the length of the current match scan and avoid another loop:

```
for (k=0; k<i-1; k++)
{
    int distance = 0;

    for (j=k+1; j<i; j++)
    { 
         if (strcmp(words[k],words[j])==0) 
         {
             printf("equal words are [%s],%d,%d,(distance = %d)",words[k],k,j,distance);
             break;
         }

         distance += strlen(words[j]);
    }  
}
```